# Sending Push Notifications do Xamarin's Android and iOs Projects

Tags: push-notification, xamarin

I am starting a mobile project using Xamarin's framework (starting with android, than, will hop into iOS) and it will be heavily dependent on Push Notifications.

Which are the current ways of sending push notifications to Xamarin's projects on both platforms ?

Comment: Take a look at this question, there is already an answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801720/push-notifications-on-all-3-platforms-android-ios-windows-phone

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp). You have to install it on your .net server, and then execute with the correct id of your phone. There are many exemple.

Comment: I use it last year for a project at work. I send notification to an android and an iOS devices. But I've not build an entire solution that store the id of the phone in a base and then push to all a notification. I just try the project pushsharp which work very well out of the github.