# Integrate Parse Push Notifications with Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am in a process to develop an app in phonegap that supports parse push notifications. I followed the following steps:

1. Create the coredova project, and navigate to the project folder using the terminal.
2. Run the parse plugin installation command:

   cordova plugin add https://github.com/benjie/phonegap-parse-plugin
3. In my DeviceReady method, I have initialized the parse:

   ```
   onDeviceReady: function() {
   var PARSE_APP = "MYPARSEAPPID";
   var PARSE_CLIENT = "MYCLIENTID";
   parsePlugin.initialize(PARSE_APP, PARSE_CLIENT, function() {
                          alert('done');
                          }, function(e) {
                          alert('error');
                          });}
   ```

   When I execute my code I successfully get the alert done, but there is no initialization in parse. Am I missing some step?

I have used XCode to run the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not copied all the code from the git link.
change parsePlugin.initialize to

```
parsePlugin.initialize(appId, clientKey, function() {

parsePlugin.subscribe('SampleChannel', function() {

    parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {

        /**
         * Now you can construct an object and save it to your own services, or Parse, and corrilate users to parse installations
         * 
         var install_data = {
            installation_id: id,
            channels: ['SampleChannel']
         }
         *
         */

    }, function(e) {
        alert('error');
    });

}, function(e) {
    alert('error');
});

}, function(e) {
alert('error');
});
```

The parsePlugin.subscribe code adds channels to your device's installation.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would move away from using parse as they are shutting [down](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/).

Some alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801720/push-notifications-on-all-3-platforms-android-ios-windows-phone).

Comment: I know that but we are going to use self hosted parse servers.